# How to set a zero offset for the frame origin?

Tags: plotting

I want to set a zero offset for the frame origin. In other words, the horizontal axis should start at exactly the lower bound, instead of having a small offset.

For example, in the figure below, even though I set the range of x to be [0, 6], the x axis starts at a small negative value. What do I need to do to make the x axis start at exactly 0?

```
Needs["PlotLegends`"]
Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 6}, Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {x, y}, 
 RotateLabel -> True, PlotLegend -> {"a=1"}, 
 LegendPosition -> {0.3, 0.3}, LegendSize -> 0.5, 
 LegendShadow -> None, LegendBorder -> None]
```

[image]

Comment: Add the option PlotRangePadding -> 0?

Comment: @DavidPark even if the solution is trivial, it *is* useful, so why not post an answer? I would also not vote for closure, but that is subjective.

Comment: @DavidPark Great. Thanks!

Comment: This is one of those "easy to find in documentetion" issues but if you now what to look for :)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is just to illustrate that the PlotRange and the padding on the Frame are independent of the domain of the Plot function.

```
Plot[Sin[x], {x, -1, 10},
 PlotRange -> {{0, 2 \[Pi]}, {-1, 1}},
 PlotRangePadding -> 0,
 Frame -> True,
 FrameTicks -> {{Automatic, Automatic}, {Range[0, 2 \[Pi], \[Pi]/2], 
    Automatic}}]
```

[image]