# X-axis offset for LogLinearPlot

Tags: plotting

I want to set a zero-offset not only for the y-axis like i did with PlotRangepadding, but also for the x-axis. 
That means i dont want the white offset left of 1E-4 and right of 1E-1, and the y-axis/frame at my o-range.

When i use the normal plot i dont get a x-axis-offset there, at least not in the positive direction.

I thought that [How to set a zero offset for the frame origin?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/30512/how-to-set-a-zero-offset-for-the-frame-origin) would solve it but it only did it for the y-axis

[image]

```
i[r_, o_] := (r*0.87)/(0.00022 + o)
LogLinearPlot[Evaluate@Table[i[r, o], {r, {100, 200, 400, 600}}], {o, 1*10^-4,0.1},PlotRangePadding -> None, PlotRange -> {0, 2500000},
```

Filling -> Axis,Frame -> True]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
LogLinearPlot[
 Evaluate@Table[i[r, o], {r, {100, 200, 400, 600}}], {o, 1*10^-4, 0.1},
 PlotRangePadding -> None,
 PlotRange -> {{1*10^-4, Automatic}, {0, 2000000}},
 Filling -> Axis, Frame -> True]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, thats exactly what i meant,